# Objective-C parameter of incompatible type 'double *'

Tags: ios, objective-c, cllocationmanager

I have this method like so:

```
    -(void)insertTracking:(NSString *)tag deviceId:(NSString *)phone latitude:(double *)latitudeId longitude:(double *)longitudeId Completetion:(void (^) (NSArray * result,NSError * error))completion{

}
```

which gives me this warning:

```
Format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'double *'
```

and this is how I am calling it:

```
[self insertTracking:barcodeHolder deviceId:[[UIDevice currentDevice] name] latitude:currentLocation.coordinate.latitude longitude:currentLocation.coordinate.longitude Completetion:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error){

}];
```

and I get this error

```
Sending 'CLLocationDegrees' (aka 'double') to parameter of incompatible type 'double *'
```

the variable longitude and latitude are coming from CLLocation how do I pass them in a double? When I insert them as string they get inserted into my database as 0 PLEASE HELP, I dont understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Is `insertTracking:deviceId:Etc:` your own method? Your main issue is that the method is expecting a `double *` and you're giving it a `double` (note the presence/absence of "*").

Comment: Remove the * from your method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those parameters should be `double`, not `double *`, assuming they are input parameters.  It's pretty rare to pass a primitive type by pointer, unless it's being used for in/out or out.

```
-(void)insertTracking:(NSString *)tag
             deviceId:(NSString *)phone
             latitude:(double)latitudeId
            longitude:(double)longitudeId
         Completetion:(void (^) (NSArray * result,NSError * error))completion;
```

(note sure why you've got `Id` at the end of their names; that is confusing).